# Magento 2 make grid row clickable without actions Column

Tags: magento2, grid

I have created one custom module and listing data from my custom module DB. All working fine. But i want to make my module grid row clickable without action column. Action column is already there but want to make full row clickable.

[image]

Here is the my xml file code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <!--Declare data source, columns list, button...-->
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">hk_commercialSale_quote_grid.hk_commercialSale_grid_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">hk_commercialSale_quote_grid.hk_commercialSale_grid_data_source</item>
            <!--Declare the data source name which will be defined below-->
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">hk_commercialSale_columns</item>
        <!--Declare the listing of columns which will be defined below-->
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Quote</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">commercialsale/index</item>
            </item>
            <!--The button on the top of the Grid-->
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="hk_commercialSale_grid_data_source">
        <!--The data source-->
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">hk_commercialSale_grid_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">hk_quote_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">hk_quote_id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
            </item>
        </argument>

        <bookmark name="bookmarks">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">commercialSale_quote_grid</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </bookmark>

        <component name="columns_controls">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">hk_commercialSale_quote_grid.hk_commercialSale_quote_grid.hk_commercialSale_columns</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns</item>
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridActions</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </component>

        <filterSearch name="fulltext">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">hk_commercialSale_quote_grid.hk_commercialSale_grid_data_source</item>
                    <item name="chipsProvider" xsi:type="string">hk_commercialSale_quote_grid.hk_commercialSale_quote_grid.listing_top.listing_filters_chips</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">hk_commercialSale_quote_grid.hk_commercialSale_quote_grid.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.search</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filterSearch>

        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">hk_commercialSale_quote_grid.hk_commercialSale_quote_grid.hk_commercialSale_columns</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">hk_commercialSale_quote_grid.hk_commercialSale_quote_grid.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">hk_commercialSale_quote_grid.hk_commercialSale_quote_grid.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                        <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">hk_commercialSale_quote_grid.hk_commercialSale_quote_grid.hk_commercialSale_columns.${ $.index }:visible</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </filters>

        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">hk_commercialSale_quote_grid.hk_commercialSale_quote_grid.hk_commercialSale_columns.ids</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <action name="delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="*/*/massDelete"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete items</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure to delete selected quotes?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>

        <paging name="listing_paging">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">hk_commercialSale_quote_grid.hk_commercialSale_quote_grid.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">hk_commercialSale_quote_grid.hk_commercialSale_quote_grid.hk_commercialSale_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </paging>

        <!--<exportButton name="export_button">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">hk_commercialSale_quote_grid.hk_commercialSale_quote_grid.hk_commercialSale_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </exportButton>-->
    </listingToolbar>

    <columns name="hk_commercialSale_columns">

        <settings>
            <childDefaults>
                <param name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">hk_commercialSale_quote_grid.hk_commercialSale_quote_grid.hk_commercialSale_columns.actions</item>
                    <item name="target" xsi:type="string">applyAction</item>
                    <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="string">view</item>
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                    </item>
                </param>
            </childDefaults>
        </settings>

        <!--The list of columns-->
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">hk_quote_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>

        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="HK\CommercialSale\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\QuoteActions">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">107</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">hk_quote_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </actionsColumn>

        <column name="hk_quote_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">desc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <column name="customer_email">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Email</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <column name="customer_name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Billing Customer Name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <column name="company_name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Billing Company Name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <column name="billing_phone">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Billing Phone Number</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <column name="billing_full">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Billing Address</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <column name="ship_customer_name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Shipping Customer Name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <column name="ship_company_name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Shipping Company Name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <column name="shipping_phone">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Shipping Phone Number</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <column name="shipping_full">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Shipping Address</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <column name="status">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">HK\CommercialSale\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Quotestatus</item>
                <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                </item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created Date</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <column name="updated_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <!--<item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>-->
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Updated Date</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <column name="followup_date" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Followup</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <!--<column name="sales_rep">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Sales Rep</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>-->

        <column name="sales_rep">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">HK\CommercialSale\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Salesrep</item>
                <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                </item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Sales Rep</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <column name="source">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">HK\CommercialSale\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Source</item>
                <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                </item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Lead Source</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <column name="reserved_order_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Order ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <column name="proposal_number">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Proposal Number</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this piece of code in ui_component grid xml under columns. "leads_listing_grid" is the name of my listing, you can replace with yours. And ".actions" in provider is the name of action column.

```
<columns name="leads_listing_grid_columns">
    <settings>
        <childDefaults>
            <param name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">leads_listing_grid.leads_listing_grid.leads_listing_grid_columns.actions</item>
                <item name="target" xsi:type="string">applyAction</item>
                <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="0" xsi:type="string">view</item>
                    <item name="1" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                </item>
            </param>
        </childDefaults>
    </settings>
    <!-- all columns -->
<!-- <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Your-actions-class"> -->
    </column>
```

Comment: Click is not working and there is error in console. TypeError: action is undefined

Comment: @hardik make sure you update data source name according you have in your file.

Comment: Yes i have updated it.

Comment: @Hardik can you update your question with the code that you have done

Comment: I have updated my question and added code that i am using.

Comment: change <item name="0" xsi:type="string">view</item> to the name of the action that you have defined in HK\CommercialSale\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\QuoteActions class (the key of that action). Check the key in datasource array if it is "view".

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: @Hardik Can you please explain me how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

These code is working but not clickable for me:

```
    <columns name="leads_listing_grid_columns">
    <settings>
        <childDefaults>
            <param name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">leads_listing_grid.leads_listing_grid.leads_listing_grid_columns.actions</item>
                <item name="target" xsi:type="string">applyAction</item>
                <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="0" xsi:type="string">view</item>
                    <item name="1" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                </item>
            </param>
        </childDefaults>
    </settings>
    <!-- all columns -->
<!-- <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Your-actions-class"> -->
    </column>
```

So I've just change this line:

```
From: 
<item name="0" xsi:type="string">view</item>

To:
<item name="0" xsi:type="string">edit</item>
```

and now its working