# How To Open Model Ui Grid Action Click Magento2?

Tags: magento2, ui-grid

I want Open Modelbox on UI grid action click based on that I want to edit my from in model box so how to achive that functionality ?

Comment: Look this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/248714/magento-2-make-grid-row-clickable-without-actions-column